# Using a nested IF statement to simulate battery but need to compute actual values not comments

Tags: excel, if-statement, battery, simulate

Trying to come up with a nested IF statement that works within a specified limit (battery state of charge) taking the necessary inputs over time.

[Sample Data Sheet]

My attempt to formulate for the State of charge operation is given below

```
= IF(AND(D5+A6-B6>=0.2*$G$1, D5+A6-B6<=0.95*$G$1), D5+A6-B6,0)

= IF(AND(D5+A6-B6<0.2*$G$1), D6= 0.2*$G$1+(D5+A6-B6).


= IF(AND(D5+A6-B6>0.95*$G$1), D6= 0.95*$G$1.


=IF(D5+A6-B6<=0.2*$G$1), 0.2*$G$1+(D5+A6-B6), IF(AND(D5+A6-B6>=0.2*$G$1, D5+A6-B6<=0.95*$G$1), D5+A6-B6,0), IF(D5+A6-B6>=0.95*$G$1), 0.95*$G$1)))

=IF(D5+A6-B6>=0.95*$G$1), 0.95*$G$1, IF(AND(D5+A6-B6>=0.2*$G$1, D5+A6-B6<=0.95*$G$1), D5+A6-B6,0), IF(D5+A6-B6<=0.2*$G$1), 0.2*$G$1+D5+A6-B6)))
```

I keep getting errors that my formulae are incorrect, please help for both state of charge and spare generation equations.

Thanks

Below is the link to the sample sheet that I have created.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kmhkBybMg18Odrow5jElcEt8RcLXqCFH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the "Sample Data Sheet" is not working.. | plus, you should check whether you have the right number of parenthesis in the formula.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. Will look at the script for the number of parenthesis as you suggested. How can I send the excel file?

Comment: just upload it in you google drive / dropbox / onedrive account. Then share the shared link for the file (by editing the question).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kmhkBybMg18Odrow5jElcEt8RcLXqCFH/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I'm Assuming the G1 value is 1 or more than 1. Also, I'm also assuming the formula is for E5 cell. Here is the proposed solution.

```
=IF((D5+A6-B6)<(0.2*$G$1),(0.2*$G$1)+(D5+A6-B6),IF((D5+A6-B6)>(0.95*$G$1), (0.95*$G$1), IF(AND((D5+A6-B6)>=(0.2*$G$1), (D5+A6-B6)<=(0.95*$G$1)), (D5+A6-B6),"not in range")))
```

Here is the same equation expanded ( to see the logic and sequence ) :

```
=IF((D5+A6-B6)<(0.2*$G$1) , (0.2*$G$1)+(D5+A6-B6),

    IF((D5+A6-B6)>(0.95*$G$1) , (0.95*$G$1),

        IF(AND( (D5+A6-B6)>=(0.2*$G$1),(D5+A6-B6)<=(0.95*$G$1)) , (D5+A6-B6),"not in range"

        )

    )

 )
```

Please have a check.